# Solving linear simultaneous equation

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases}
3x - y + z&= 9\\
y - z &= 6
\end{cases}
$$

I eliminated and reached a solution of $$\begin{align}x &= 5\\y &= \lambda\\ z &= \lambda - 6\end{align}$$
where $\lambda$ is a real constant.

However, the solution says that $$\begin{align}x &= 1 - \frac{2}{3}\lambda\\ y &= 6 - \lambda\\ z &= \lambda\end{align}$$

Comment: You can substitute and verify that your solutions is satisfies the equations and the other doesn't.

Comment: $y-z=6$, using the given solution you get $y-z=6-2\lambda$. Either given solution is wrong or you did not copy the statement of the problem correctly

Comment: I copied it down correctly, so their solution must be wrong. So just to make sure, I am right ?! @Vasili

Comment: @NikitaMazepin: your solution looks good to me

Comment: It looks like they solved $y + z = 6$ and chose $\lambda = z$ instead of $\lambda = y$ as you did. Something more went wrong with the first equation, but I don't spot any obvious choices for the mistake.